# How to insert multiple rows by mysqli_multi_query()?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to do multiple insertions using `mysqli_multi_query()` and following is my code. The issue is its not executing the result . Kindly let me know what i did wrong?

```
$query = "INSERT INTO crap_table (name, number, class)VALUES ('Peter', 35,'BS')";
$query .= "INSERT INTO crap_table (name, number, class)VALUES ('Sahil', 35,'MS')";
mysqli_multi_query($con,$query);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[mysqli_multi_query](https://www.php.net/mysqli_multi_query)**

> Executes one or multiple queries which are concatenated by a semicolon.

You need to have a `;` between them. Like

```
$query = "INSERT INTO crap_table (name, number, class)VALUES ('Peter', 35,'BS');";
                                                                               ^
$query .= "INSERT INTO crap_table (name, number, class)VALUES ('Sahil', 35,'MS')";
```

Provided that you are connected to the database already? Like

```
$con= mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
```

Comment: Please select this answer as the approved answer if this is the answer you needed. It's the little checkmark under the vote number.

Comment: @DenizZoeteman I would have selected it earlier but due to 8 mins constraint i could not

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO crap_table (name, number, class)VALUES ('Peter', 35,'BS');";
$query .= "INSERT INTO crap_table (name, number, class)VALUES ('Sahil', 35,'MS')";
mysqli_multi_query($con,$query);
```

You forgot `;` between your queries.

> Executes one or multiple queries which are concatenated by a
>   semicolon.